# how to rotate the yellow cube towards the car?

Tags: godot

how to rotate the yellow cube towards the car ? I have a spinning camera, I think this is the case
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to do with with code? *I remind you StackOverflow is for programming. For other game related things there is [gamedev.stackexchange.com](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com).*

---

If you are doing this with code - and given that I don't know how the scene tree looks like - I suggest using `look_at`. Something like this (code for the `Camera`):

```
look_at(car.global_transform.origin, car.global_transform.basis.y)
```

There `car` is a reference to the car. *I can't tell you how to get one without looking at the scene tree, beyond that you can probably use `get_node`.* So `car.global_transform.origin` is the position of the car in global coordinates. And `car.global_transform.basis.y` is the direction towards the up of the car.

The method `look_at` needs an up vector because there are infinite ways to look at a given point (rotate around the view line). Thus, we do not want an up vector that matches the view line. *For example, `Vector3.UP` won't work if the camera is looking directly up or directly down.*

---

And if you just want to rotate this in the designer. You can use the gizmo you see when you select it. You can drag the blue ring until it is aligned correctly.

The de facto standard for this gizmos is that `x` is red, `y` is green, and `z` is blue (this is true in Godot, Blender, and plenty of other software). So the blue ring rotates around the z axis. You can also find that rotation in the inspector panel, look for rotation degrees for the z under transform.

---

I remind you that if you place the `Camera` as a child node of another `Spatial`, it will keep its position and orientation relative to it. So placing the `Camera` as child of your player character (e.g. a `KinematicBody`) is often good enough for the early stages of development, as that guarantees that the `Camera` follows the player character. No coding necessary. *You may want a more elaborate `Camera` control later, which would require some code.*

Since you mention "spinning camera", perhaps you want a `Camera` that orbits around a point. The easier way to do this is to add an auxiliary `Spatial` for the point the `Camera` rotates around. *Let us call it `Pivot`, and rotate that.* For clarity, I'm suggesting a setup like this:

```
PlayerCharacter
└ Pivot
  └ Camera
```

Here the `Pivot` follows the player character. And the `Camera` follows the `Pivot`. So moving the player character moves the `Camera`, and rotating the `Pivot` makes the `Camera` orbit. This is just lacking some code to make the `Pivot` rotate. For example something like this (code for `Pivot`):

```
global_transform.rotate_y(Input.get_axis("camera_left", "camera_right"))
```

Where `"camera_left"` and `"camera_right"` are actions configured in the Input Map (in Project settings). *Which reminds me, you can set actions from code with `Input.action_press`, so there could be code somewhere else (e.g. `_input`) writing these actions from mouse movement.*

*Camera Control does not have to be hard.*